# WPF Screen Resolution Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and a dual monitor system. I have an application running on a screen with resolution 1920*1080. But when I drag and drop it to another screen of resolution 1366*768, the screen becomes scrollable. The content is not fitting the screen width. I need to scroll to see the other content.

Right now I am fetching the width of the active screen and calculating the width of all the controls. The screenWidth variable has the right value but it is not getting reflected.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Please add xaml code to your question as solution depends on how it is currently done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Viewbox control, it will scale to fit the content to the available size. Hope you have not given fixed sized to grid. Use grid layout & width should always be kept to "auto".

```
<Viewbox>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="12">ABC</TextBlock>               
        </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```